# Create frequency tables using group_by function

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
       Indicator     Answer_1     Answer_2    Answer_3
          0            Correct    Wrong         Wrong
          1            Partial    Correct       Wrong
          1            Wrong      Wrong         Wrong
          0            Correct    Correct       Wrong
```

I have about 150 observations and 15 answers (so the answer variable is upto Answer_15). I want to create a frequency table of Correct, Partial and Wrong, grouped by Indicator (signifying if the student was in the control or treatment group). Ideally, it would look like this:

```
        Indicator      Correct     Partial      Wrong
            0            x           y            z
            1            a           b            c
```

where x, y, z and a, b, c are the total number of times 'Correct', 'Wrong' and 'Partial' appeared across Answer_1, Answer_2... Answer_15.

I've tried using the group_by(Indicator)%>% summarise(c(Answer_1, ..., Answer_15)), but this isn't working. Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Please share a reproducible piece of your data so that others can use it in order to help you. How does a partial answer is provided by data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data in long format, count occurrence of each value for unique value of `Indicator` and cast the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Answer')) %>%
  count(Indicator, value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

#  Indicator Correct Wrong Partial
#      <int>   <int> <int>   <int>
#1         0       3     3       0
#2         1       1     4       1
```

You can make code a little shorter using `janitor::tabyl`.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Answer')) %>%
  janitor::tabyl(Indicator, value)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Indicator = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Answer_1 = c("Correct", 
"Partial", "Wrong", "Correct"), Answer_2 = c("Wrong", "Correct", 
"Wrong", "Correct"), Answer_3 = c("Wrong", "Wrong", "Wrong", 
"Wrong")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```